# How can I know uitextfield has be hit when it is first responder

Tags: ios, events, uitextfield

I make a textfield to comment, comment can have emotion or any other content like tag. so I will change the textfield 's input view from keyboard to custom view, and I need when I touch the textfield again, the input view should be keyboard again. Now I cannot receive the event that touch textfield again.

Thank you!

edit 1:

I have a ugly but useful way now.I add another textfield that hide back, when show emotion the second textfield become first responder. then touch the first textfield will show keyboard as usually .

I think it's not so good, if you have any better way please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your textfield when touched the first time has become the first responder which you can detect in the following [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidBeginEditing%3a). If you touch it again, you wont receive the event because the textfield hasnt resigned the responder yet. What you may try is to detect touches over the frame of the textfield after it has begun editing and then show the keyboard.

Comment: yes,just like your said, the textfield just notificate first time. I think it's some complex for me to try your way to fix it, I just study ios 2 month. Now , I have a ugly way but useful. I add another textfield that hide back, when show emotion the second textfield become first responder.

Comment: what you may try is add a tap gesture recognizer to your textfield and assign an action method for it. In that you can check if the textfield is currently the first responder and show/hide keyboard

Comment: how to add a tap gesture recognizer? can you give me an sample?

Comment: write this line in say viewDidLoad() `[self.yourTextField addGestureRecognizer:[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped)] autorelease]];` where yourTextField is an `IBOutlet` connected to the textfield and `textFieldTapped` is the method which will trigger when the textfield is tapped. Inside this method you can check `if([yourTextField isFirstResponder])`.. then show/hide keyboard. Make sure you specify the number of Taps as 1 for the gesture recognizer.

Comment: Welcome, here is also a [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) on gesture recognizers.